# PHP file does not receive data from AJAX post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tablePend tbody').on('click','.btn',function(){
        // var id=$('#test-pend').val();
        var currow=$(this).closest("tr");
        var colId = currow.find('td:eq(3)').text();
        var id = colId;
        alert(id);
        $.post("../admin/detail.php", {
            pid:id
        });
    });
});
```

So the code above works perfectly, the alert shows the result that I want

```
<?php
include('dbh.inc.php');
include_once('header.php');

if(isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pid']);
    $sql= "SELECT event_name, event_desc, event_date, event_id FROM events WHERE event_id='$id'";
    $result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    echo $id;
} else {
    echo 'nothing';
}

include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

So right here, the PHP automatically goes to the else statement which shows nothing, I don't know what went wrong, I've tried all possible ways, for days, this is really making me frustrated, and I also believe that I made a simple mistake but I can't find it.

Comment: Your `if` test should be `if(isset($_POST['pid'])) {`, not `if(!isset($_POST['pid'])) {`

Comment: ouhhh sorry ,i forgot to change that, i've already tried before this that what you suggest, and it still does not work

Comment: what does "still does not work" mean?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['pid'])) {, not if(!isset($_POST['pid'], i,ve tried doing what you asked, and the same error still occurs

Comment: It's not possible to get the same output if you change the `if` condition. Either you will get the word `nothing` or you will get the value of `$id`.

Comment: so what do i need to change in the code for me to get the $id, because right now it only shows nothing

Comment: is the filename of your `php` is `detail.php` and in correct directory?

Comment: yes the filename is detail.php and it is in the correct directory

Comment: What do you get if you `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: do i need to put print_r($_POST);  outside the if else statement? edit: i've put print_r($_POST); out the if else statement and it shows this Array ( ) nothing

Comment: If `print_r($_POST);` gives you `Array ()` then there are no values in the `$_POST` array, which means that your ajax query is not working properly. You should add `.done` and `.fail` callbacks to your `$.post` to see if you are getting an error from that

Comment: how do I use **.done** and **.fail**  inside my js file, never use those, sorry

Comment: @MuhdIqbal Did my answer help, or did I misunderstand how you are seeing `nothing`?

Comment: `Don't Panic`, the actual reason why I use jqury in the first place is that, I needed to access a value in a table tag, so after accessing it, I want to send it to a php file and make data display on that php file based on the data I access, but from the reasearch that I made, it is said that I needed to use js to access the data in html table, and in order to send it to another php file, i need to do it through ajax, so I've done that, and the result is like the question I stated here

Comment: After that, Khang Than mentions that the data I want it to be display based on the data I received will be display on the page same with the html table, so that's why I get the output nothing, right now, what I want is just to send the value I access to another php file and display it huhuhuhu

Comment: @MuhdIqbal Your code is correct for getting data from the table and sending it via AJAX to PHP, without leaving the page with the table.  You can get a response from that PHP file, and for eg "live update" the page you are on, without refreshing or reloading.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do some sleuthing to come up with this answer.

Your `$.post()` jQuery code does not include a success (or error) handler.  That means no matter what happens, you won't see the results of what your PHP file says.  But in your question, you say you can see `nothing`.  So, this makes me suspect that you are not actually submitting via AJAX at all.

You have shown us jQuery code where you have an event handler attached to your button.  My guess is your button is inside a a `<form>`.  When you click a button in a form, it will submit it.  If you want your jQuery to handle it instead, you have to explicitly specify that the normal form submission should not happen.  And your your jQuery code does not do that.

So what all this means is that when you click the button, the form is submitted *normally*.  Your event handler maybe fires, and that code starts, but meanwhile the browser has moved on to your `<form>` target, and the jQuery never gets far.  Your `<form>` does not actually include an `id`, you set that dynamically with jQuery.  So you wind up on the `<form>` target, with no `id` POSTed, and you see `nothing` on the page.

The fix is to stop the normal form submission:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tablePend tbody').on('click','.btn',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // rest of your code
```

Note I have added `event` as a parameter passed to the event handler, and then used its `preventDefault()` method.  There is an example of this shown in the [`.post()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).